# Verifying that two words match — false negatives

Tags: unity, c#, debugging

In my first game, I am trying to validate whether two words match: whether an input word matches a reference word from an array.

Unfortunately the only word for which it finds a correct match is the last value in the array I created. All the other words report an incorrect match even when input correctly.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MatchLetters : MonoBehaviour {
    public string word = null;
    public int wordIndex = 0;
    public string alpha;
    public Text WordMatch;
    public Text Question;
    public string name;
    public static string[] quest;
    int num;
    public List<string> Words;

    void Start () {
        TextAsset wordText = Resources.Load<TextAsset> ("Words");

        quest = wordText.text.Split ("\n" [0]);
    }

    void Update () {
       //  Question.text = quest[Random.Range(0, quest.Length)];
    }
    public void AlphabeticFunction(string alphabet){
        wordIndex++;
        word = word + alphabet;
        WordMatch.text = word;
    }

    public void WordsGenerate (){
        name = Question.text = quest[Random.Range(0, quest.Length)];
    }

    public void ValidateAnswer (){

        if (name == WordMatch.text) {
            Question.color = Color.green;
            Debug.Log ("Correct");
        } else {
            Question.color = Color.red;
            Debug.Log ("Incorrect");
        }
    }

    public void ResetAnswer(){
        wordIndex = 0;
        word = "";
        WordMatch.text = word;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you walked through the other words character-by-character to see where they differ? My bet it you're splitting on CR characters and leaving stray LFs in your strings

Comment: I didn't quite get what you said hahaha, I am so sorry.

Comment: what are CR and LF?

Comment: Don't underestimate your ability to [find answers through your own research](https://www.google.com/search?q=cr+lf+character)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want do to some form of pattern matching.  There's many ways to do that.  I coded up a quick example.  I left out the Unity specifics, but should be able to easily take what I wrote and put modify it for your project.

I created a class that contains a method called `CountOfInputThatExist` that does the matching.  The method is more important.  I think that is what you want.

```
public class WordMatchMaking
{
    // this is the list of words you load from your asset
    // that you called WordText in your code
    public List<string> PossibleWords = new List<string>();

    public int CountOfInputThatExist(string input)
    {
        int matchesFound = 0;

        foreach(string validWord in PossibleWords)
        {
            if (input.Contains(validWord))
                matchesFound++;
        }

        return matchesFound;
    }
}
```

And here's the code being used:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WordMatchMaking matchTest = new WordMatchMaking();

        // this is how I initialize my example.  Its similar to
        // your Resources.Load call
        matchTest.PossibleWords.AddRange(new string[] { "cat", "dog", "bird", "fish" });

        string test = "my cat is hungry.";
        Console.WriteLine($"testing '{test}' found {matchTest.CountOfInputThatExist(test)} occurrences.");

        test = "I have a cat and a dog.";
        Console.WriteLine($"testing '{test}' found {matchTest.CountOfInputThatExist(test)} occurrences.");

        test = "The snake ate the fish.";
        Console.WriteLine($"testing '{test}' found {matchTest.CountOfInputThatExist(test)} occurrences.");

        Console.WriteLine("\r\n\r\ntest done...press any key to end application");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

And here's the output:

```
testing 'my cat is hungry.' found 1 occurrences.
testing 'I have a cat and a dog.' found 2 occurrences.
testing 'The snake ate the fish.' found 1 occurrences.
```

If you have any questions about this, please ask.  I hope it helps.  Please remember to mark this as an answer, if you find this helpful.